# In oops concept does class occupy memory

Tags: java

As per the definition in Java. If class doesn't occupy memory and just acts like a template, then why are we creating objects(main method) inside curly braces of class. Doesn't that mean now class also occupies memory because of objects present inside of it?

Trying to understand the definition of a class

Comment: Conceptually, a class is an abstraction - barring something like reflection, it is not something that interacts with other things in your program at runtime. Object instances of a class interact with other objects during the lifetime of a program.  I suggest writing some reflection code in Java, and coming back with a more concrete question.

Comment: Everything uses memory, computers don't do magic. It'd be helpful if you could quote the exact text that made that claim.

Comment: `main` is always confusing to new programmers because it is `static`. Things that are `static` "belong to the class", instead of belonging to a specific instance of the class. This is what makes them "shared" between all instances of the class. `static` things belong to the class, without needing an instance of the class. So, yes, if a class had no static members at all, then it would not take up any memory since you'd have to create an instance of it first before you could use it. `static` members will exist as soon as the program starts, and will take up memory for the lifetime of the app.

Answer (score 3):

There are three concepts to keep separate here: the *class*, the *instance*, and the *stack*.

```java
class SomeClass {
  static int staticValue = 0;

  /* non-static */ int instanceValue = 0;

  int someMethod() {
    int stackValue = 42;
    SomeClass instance = new SomeClass();
    // ...
  }
}
```

The class acts as a template, yes. In some languages other than Java, the class takes up no memory of its own: it merely describes the memory layout of the class's instances. For a beginner definition of OOP concepts you can think of that as true.

In Java this is not *quite* true for three reasons:

1. There is an object instance for SomeClass, accessible via `SomeClass.class`, which does take up memory. This instance allows you to look up information about the class itself, which is sometimes called "reflection".
2. The static field `staticValue` is shared among all instances of SomeClass, so in a sense the class takes up a small amount of memory to contain this shared value.
3. SomeClass contains methods like `someMethod`, and that code has to be in memory in order to run. If you're willing to consider code as requiring memory, and that the code is associated with the class, then the class consumes memory. People talking about OOP concepts aren't usually talking about the memory consumed by the code itself, though.

This can be compared to *instances* of the class SomeClass, which at a minimum contain a separate value of `instanceValue` for every instance you create. Instances don't have their own code, and do (in Java) contain a reference to their Class instance accessible via `getClass()`.

Finally, the method `someMethod` and your `main` example do use references and local variables that consume memory, but in a different place than the instances or classes. This place is called a "stack", in part because as you call methods and those call further methods, the stack grows like a stack of papers on a desk. This means that there may be many copies of `stackValue` existing at once, one for each time you have called `someMethod` that hasn't finished yet. Each value of `stackValue` is discarded whenever its corresponding invocation of `someMethod` returns. These aren't directly tied to classes or instances, other than that they are code that might be considered associated with a class as in #3 above. Disregarding the memory consumed by the compiled code itself, the `instance` does not contribute to SomeClass or its instances consuming any more memory in ways that matter to OOP.

(Instances created with `new` are not a part of a "stack" but rather are part of the "heap", at this level of explanation, and that includes the `SomeClass.class` instance and any instances of SomeClass. Some languages require careful management of the heap's memory, but Java manages it for you through a process called *garbage collection*. Primitives like `stackValue` and the *reference* named `instance` are kept on the stack, though.)